# How can I create an interactive mockup of my Photoshop web design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, software-recommendation, mockup

This is my first time doing this. I made a web design in Photoshop and I don't know what to do next. I have to show other people the website and I was think of using WebEx. Is there another software I can put my design in to and then it will work as a website or do I have to get another software and make the design again?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to show the site the best alternative to demo it would be to code it as HTML and CSS.  If you made the design with vectors you could try testing to see if the vectors could be converted to SVG and open the file in a browser however in gradients or effects will not transition properly.  In the future I would suggest designing in Illustrator but in reality the best thing to do would be to design in the browser with code.

I have heard of paid conversion tools that can take a psd and turn it to HTML but Ive never used one and suggesting one isnt in scope with the site as it could be considered as spam and the link  can rot as though services come and go.

So to sum up, at this time there really isn't a one click solution that Im aware of.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question, I don't know coding. I'm working for a small company and I need to make mockups. That I can click on and go to other pages. Please can you tell me a software or way that I can do it because right now I have only made the first page if I need to start using any other software I can. Thanks once again for reply back to me.

Comment: Someone mind explaining the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

@Mike, I think @DarthVader addressed your question quite well. But just to throw more light on your follow up question, there are a host of good tools out there that can help your workflow with little or no coding at all. Since your workflow is in Adobe Photoshop, Adobe has *Adobe [Experience Design](http://www.adobe.com/products/experience-design.html)* that works seemlessly with Photoshop. Visit their Learn and support [page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-design.html) for a quick start up. *[InVision](https://www.invisionapp.com/)*, is another interactive web prototyping tool that [integrates](https://www.invisionapp.com/photoshop-prototyping) well with Photoshop. *[UXPin](https://www.uxpin.com/)* also [supports Photoshop](https://www.uxpin.com/community/tutorials/imports-from-photoshop/) imports, *[Proto.io](https://proto.io/)* too has great support Photoshop, and *[Justinmind](http://www.justinmind.com/)*, allows great prototyping options though its Photoshop integration/workflow is a bit limited.

**Note** that there are a host of great tools out there and choosing what you wish to work with is a matter of your budget and person preference.

Comment: There are a host of "tools" out there. I wouldn't accuse any of being great, or even good.

Comment: @Confused You're essentially drawing a rectangle on top of an area and then saying show this image when it's clicked. What could these applications possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Put it like that, you make me wonder why making websites isn't just point-n-click = Webby!!!

Comment: Maybe I'm @Confused, because I though that these applications are not for making websites?

Comment: You're getting distracted. The claim is that these tools are great. I'm disputing that because I think it's wrong to plant false hope of 'great' software experiences when the entire field offers nothing of the sort.

Comment: @Confused, greatness is relative. Just because something does not meet your satisfaction doesn't disqualify it from greatness in the hands of others. It depends on how you use the tool. Someone would say *Notepad* is great for coding websites and another might call it feeble. From your point of view, I would really wish to hear what's lacking of the Prototyping tools out there so far.